# Spring Boot Rest search 404

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I noticed periodically that `/search` doesn't seem to work on my `@RepositoryRestResource`:

### Spring Boot Output

```
2014-08-25 13:37:51.526  INFO 10645 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2014-08-25 13:37:51.526  INFO 10645 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2014-08-25 13:37:51.526  INFO 10645 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2014-08-25 13:37:51.526  INFO 10645 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2014-08-25 13:37:51.526  INFO 10645 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
```

---

### curl on /persons

```
curl http://localhost:8080/persons
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "firstName" : "Jimmy",
      "lastName" : "Neutron",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/2"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Jimmy",
      "lastName" : "Page",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/3"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "firstName" : "Jimmy",
      "lastName" : "Johns",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/4"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 3,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
```

### cURL on /search

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/persons/search
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f9903004400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f9903004400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /persons/search HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Mon, 25 Aug 2014 18:55:27 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Usually I can restart the Application and it randomly appears with 0 changes:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/persons
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 0,
    "totalPages" : 0,
    "number" : 0
  }
```

Is there something needed to enable search functionality 100% of the time?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found out that causes it.

Spring loads only one repository for your domain type to find search resource mappings. If you have multiple repositories for your domain type, spring somehow randomly selects one and uses that one. If that one does not contain your custom search method, it does not load.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite buy the randomness argument, but if you can really reproduce it, feel free to open a ticket in our tracker.

The general rule is that the search resource is only exposed if there's at least a single query method exposed (i.e. a query method that's not actively configured to not be exported) on the repository in question.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't really let clients construct URIs on the fly but rather inspect the response for links and follow them. Thus, I'd argue that if you get the first response, performing a call to `/search` is invalid as the client has no reason to assume the resource to even exist. If you start with the second response, you can discover a `search` link advertising a search resource being available and follow it.

Comment: I see this as more of a symptom so random is probably a bad choice of words. My repository references a named query, native query, and derived property query so I would expect search to be there. I've noticed this occurs if I `POST` before doing a `GET` after boot starts up. I wouldn't call `/search` but that was to illustrate the 404. Given your explanation, wouldn't you expect the search link to be there in my `/persons` example?

Comment: Yes, I'd love to see a tiny example project (GitHUb maybe?) that illustrates the behavior you see.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue from time to time and i am strangling to understand the nature of it. When it happens i am spending hours of changing code, re-compiling, rebuilding until somehow it works.
Could it be some auto generated cached code or something like that? Or some race condition when registering rest methods?

In addition: i had the issue on my local dev environment, fixed it by clean rebuild, but with the same code base i still can not fix it on my qa env..

Answer (score 1):

Getting random "Not Found" error can happen in case you have multiple repositories defined for the same domain object. It is a known Spring Data Rest bug which happens due to undeterministic order in which those repositories are discovered/registered.

Please vote at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-923 to get it fixed.